# Box.net 'drag and drop files' code?

Tags: php, ajax, web-applications, web, box-api

I wanted to know how is box.net's drag and drop files functionality implemented.

Can anyone show some sample code as to how to implement the functionality in a browser??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a tutorial.

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/

Comment: thx that helped..though i noticed that box.net's drag and drop is implemented through flash...any more answers as to how to do it through flash??